# Typescript make sure given param is an instance of an object that implements an interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which declares a method. The method accepts some parameters and one of the parameters must be any object that implements another interface. How can I make this check?

```
interface SkematicValidatorInterface {
    validate(resource: SkematicModelInterface, value:any);
}
```

As you probably have guessed already, somewhere in my code I have another interface called `SkematicModelInterface` that must be the foundation of every `resource` being passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method accepts some parameters and one of the parameters must be any object that implements another interface ...  I have another interface called `SkematicModelInterface` that must be the foundation of every resource being passed ... How can I make this check?

## Solution

Your interface :

```
interface SkematicValidatorInterface {
    validate(callback: (resource: SkematicModelInterface, value:any) => void) : void;
}
```

is exactly the check you are looking for.

## Usage:

```
interface SkematicModelInterface{
    data: string;
}

interface SkematicValidatorInterface {
    validate(callback: (resource: SkematicModelInterface, value:any) => void) : void;
}

var foo: SkematicValidatorInterface;

var c1 = (resource: number, value: any) => null;
var c2 = (resource: SkematicModelInterface, value: any) => null;

foo.validate(c1); // Error
foo.validate(c2); // Okay
```

Comment: I must be really smart then :)) I honestly just started playing with TS and put some things together and I really thought I can't be that lucky and get it right the first time. Thanks.